# How to improve message for jpackage install dialog in MSI

Tags: java, windows-installer, jpackage, orca, java-21

This script created [jDiskMark-0.5.1.msi](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jdiskmark/files/jDiskMark-0.5.1.msi/download) with [jpackage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html). When I run the installer it will list a name of a msi which is not the same as the msi file I packaged and ran which is miss leading to a user.

```
set VERSION=0.5.1
set JPKG_EXE="C:\Program Files\java\jdk-21\bin\jpackage"

%JPKG_EXE% --type msi --input jdiskmark-v%VERSION% --main-jar jDiskMark.jar ^
    --name jDiskMark-%VERSION% --app-version %VERSION% ^
    --vendor "jdiskmark.net" --win-console --win-menu
```

In the below image the text "2a243a02.msi" is confusing because a user just double clicked a file named *jDiskMark-0.5.1.msi* to run the installer. It is more ideal to show the file the user launched or something else.
[image]

In the msi installer for Microsoft Orca they set this message to "Microsoft Windows" instead of the name of the MSI file being installed. I believe that is a better approach but I do not know how to set this message. What is this field called and how can I set it?

NOTE: i have tried the jpackage --description option already which does not set this message.

I am using jpackage from jdk 21 on windows 11. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your UAC dialog looks different to Windows 10, which always shows full path to the MSI as the first field (have tested this is same for me on JDK21/22). Perhaps this is down to Windows version, or maybe the MSI is compressed in some way and expanded to a temp location beforehand, and so UAC shows expanded and compressed file?

Comment: I'm packaging on windows 11. What was interesting is a recent attempt showed the full path. I feel this field is settable just trying to figure out how. When you run the installer for MS Orca they set it to "Microsoft Windows" I feel like if someone can tell me the name of this field it would be faster to find out how to set it.